# AQL doesn't generate expected result

Tags: arangodb

I use ArangoDB v3.9.0

Following AQL doesn't calculate numberEmployeesAccumulated correctly. 1057 records becomes 0 insted of correct result.

```
FOR n IN biz_scd_departments

LET childs = (
FOR m IN biz_scd_departments
FILTER n.department IN m.departmentIndexBoost
FILTER m.numberEmployees > 0
RETURN m.numberEmployees
)

LET nea = SUM(childs)

UPDATE { _key: n._key }
WITH { numberEmployeesAccumulated: nea }
IN biz_scd_departments
```

if I comment out the UPDATE section, the returned result is correct. So I assume the behaviour has something to do with write operations.

I did change the query to this:

```
LET data = (
    FOR n IN biz_scd_departments
    
    LET childs = (
    FOR m IN biz_scd_departments
    FILTER n.department IN m.departmentIndexBoost
    FILTER m.numberEmployees > 0
    RETURN m.numberEmployees
    )
    
    LET nea = SUM(childs)
    RETURN { _key: n._key, nea: nea }
)

LET write = (
    FOR d IN data
    UPDATE { _key: d._key, numberEmployeesAccumulated: d.nea }
    IN biz_scd_departments 
)

return {}
```

Now, every record has the right value under numberEmployeesAccumulated property.

My question is: why the first query doesn't generate correct result? Is it a bug in ArangoDB or am I simply doing something wrong?

Comment: Your first query seems to be missing a return statement.

Comment: as for now, it looks like rockdb configuration option 'intermediate-commit-count' = 300 causes this issue... when disabled, result is correct.

Comment: Intermediate-commits can have some influence (in particular in older versions which had some issues with the read-own-write behavior), but I don't see how this would affect your query, since your subquery does not depend on the value written by the update.